# Where is admin:// protocol in GTK4?

Tags: linux, gtk, gnome, nautilus

In previous versions of Nautilus File Manager (built on GTK3) , I used to just type `admin://` before full-path of a directory (e.g. `admin:///usr/share/applications/`) and it opened that directory with elevated privilages.

I can't do that in newer version of Nautilus File Manager (built on GTK4).

Since `admin://` protocol is not available in GTK4, I tried googling an alternative to GTK3's `admin://` protocol for elevated privilages in Nautilus. I could'nt find anything.

If any gnome dev is reading this, is there an alternative available in GTK4 or not?